# How to extend style in styled component but change only tag properties?

Tags: react-native, styled-components

I'm using React native with styled components
I have an AddTag component with a TouchableOpacity tag and a Tag component with a View tag. Here, I want to extend AddTag to inherit only style from Tag, but give View tag to Tag component.
Is there no way?

I want to get rid of duplication. This is my full code.

```
  const AddTag = styled.TouchableOpacity`
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  margin: 4px;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
`;

const Tag = styled.View`
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  margin: 4px;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
`;

      <TagContainer>
        <AddTag onPress={AddTagFunc}>
          <Icon
            style={{marginRight: 7}}
            source={require('~/Assets/btn_add.png')}
          />
          <Text>Add</Text>
        </AddTag>
      </TagContainer>

      <TagContainer>
        <Tag>
          <Text>Hello</Text>
          <Icon
            style={{width: 15, height: 15, marginLeft: 8}}
            source={require('~/Assets/del_tag.png')}
          />
        </Tag>
      </TagContainer>
```